# Monitoring incoming/outgoing packets on a Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switch, ios

I would like to monitor (i.e. have the switch print out packets) incoming and/or outgoing packets on a Cisco switchport.

For instance, I'd like to be able to tell it: `Print to the log all packets arriving on Gi0/1`.

Something tells me this should be easy, but I can't find any way to do so!

I am aware that I could set up a mirror port, however for this particular scenario that won't be useful.

Comment: Are you actually trying to get a copy of every single packet on the port?  Mirror/SPAN/RSPAN is the "correct" answer - a debug will kill the CPU on the router.

Comment: I don't even remember the original circumstances that led to me asking this question, but according to above I am aware I could set up a mirror port but it wouldn't be useful for that particular case.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't realize how old this was.  I guess I'm trying to understand the circumstances of "I want a copy of every packet" but "Span won't work".

Comment: No worries - it's actually good for site to get activity on old (especially unanswered) questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

debug packet interface gi0/1

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/debug/command/reference/dbfmodem.html#wp1060637

Important Note:

> Because the debug packet  command
>   generates a substantial amount of
>   output for every packet processed, use
>   it only when traffic on the network is
>   low, so other activity on the system
>   is not adversely affected.

Comment: A good answer, but not supported on any of my hardware (C2960, C3012, CIGESM, 2621 router). Any info on which versions of IOS support `debug packet interface`?